# Incoherent data Firebase listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a listener that reads the last 10 comments from a Firebase real-time database:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase                from './Firebase';

const GetLastComments = (numberOfComments) => {
    
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
   
    useEffect( () => {
        
        let ref = firebase.database().ref('replies');
      
        let listener = ref.limitToLast(numberOfComments).on('value', snapshot => { 
            
            let replies = snapshot.val();
           
            if(replies){
                
                let sortedReplies = Object.entries(replies);
                
                console.log(sortedReplies);
                
                setComments(sortedReplies);
                
            } 
            
        });
        
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
     
    }, [numberOfComments]);
    
    return comments;
  
}

export default GetLastComments;
```

The listener returns the following array of comments:

[image]

Whereas if I take a look at the last comments on the Firebase real-time database:

```json
{
    "-MXqERpw8UB4cj-A_dVt" : {
    "message" : "ra56h, no te olvides del cuarto caso: jefes que parecen demonios... y lo son.  :-D",
    "postId" : "-MXnHbLBLvHz5Bb8JUl7",
    "timeStamp" : 1617965206904,
    "userName" : "Antonio Socías Carrillo",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj7AshIUFLsWtMAIt-aukeSREGitv9ky7chZ3g1vfA=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "CTDLa2Yza3Q5F64l7nIdmpGdX5O2"
    },
    "-MXqYv2T2cOGeSKEXl3D" : {
    "message" : "jjajajjaja ese es el más común de todos (por desgracia). ",
    "postId" : "-MXnHbLBLvHz5Bb8JUl7",
    "timeStamp" : 1617970573603,
    "userName" : "ra56h",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ACtC-3dSNabK7sxT20pXvm0WquorPunx2LafRMvwISjKmmazopdrPJpZVljzt8VJDpC3KLHC9haBhY-ST2tuvhlpzgbKz_dmRXhjhBU12-wSjPnb_hxko0GlaCMPw6cdHCzj8giNJyAdQh0QvqtQTlWrYhArEw=s700-no?authuser=0",
    "userUid" : "ra56h"
    },
    "-MXsL4QYpvtaAXimUKYT" : {
    "message" : "Esto parece el día de la marmota, me cago en mis cojones. No vamos a salir de este bucle jamás. Hoy he oído en mi curro que en España también se avecinan un par de semanitas de resaca de coronavirus post Semana Santa. ",
    "postId" : "-MXqi6VDUbzRyBhhhfuG",
    "timeStamp" : 1618000500522,
    "userName" : "Pimper Pamper",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMZPa1zJQcNXYQFeYzOlZbhwTw_Rx0d0sgRXUy=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "ftCIbYCfXYQ4tEd4ByCkvVuqjlI2"
    },
    "-MXsMJr3sA9uuV9J8TKx" : {
    "message" : "A sus órdenes, mi capitán, para servirle a usted y a España. La causa de la desaparición de los mensajes seguramente sea causa de rojos e izquierdistas. Piense que todos los grandes problemas de la humanidad vienen de la izquierda. ",
    "postId" : "-MXfuqfe8Qoq__AUQYwT",
    "timeStamp" : 1618000825867,
    "userName" : "Pimper Pamper",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMZPa1zJQcNXYQFeYzOlZbhwTw_Rx0d0sgRXUy=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "ftCIbYCfXYQ4tEd4ByCkvVuqjlI2"
    },
    "-MXsNYEUXFJQpUq0EiPx" : {
    "message" : "Lo peor son los jefes que son más jóvenes que tú y que te dan más órdenes que el gerente de la empresa.",
    "postId" : "-MXnHbLBLvHz5Bb8JUl7",
    "timeStamp" : 1618001146918,
    "userName" : "Pimper Pamper",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMZPa1zJQcNXYQFeYzOlZbhwTw_Rx0d0sgRXUy=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "ftCIbYCfXYQ4tEd4ByCkvVuqjlI2"
    },
    "-MY5mK-HSRYsdQSugz8M" : {
    "message" : "Mi jefe de área se acaba de jubilar después de 30 años en la empresa. Un tío majísimo.\n\nAcaba de entrar uno joven que parece guay. Veremos qué pasa.",
    "postId" : "-MXnHbLBLvHz5Bb8JUl7",
    "timeStamp" : 1618242786863,
    "userName" : "Antonio Socías Carrillo",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj7AshIUFLsWtMAIt-aukeSREGitv9ky7chZ3g1vfA=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "CTDLa2Yza3Q5F64l7nIdmpGdX5O2"
    },
    "-MY6OAKzjBtsyguNQheb" : {
    "message" : "Cuidado con Revolut, que ahora mismo le pisa los talones a N26. Desde hace poco te devuelven un 1% de tus compras en efectivo con la tarjeta metal. ",
    "postId" : "-MY4N5pmKxoaKlmNGgbj",
    "timeStamp" : 1618252969412,
    "userName" : "Pimper Pamper",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMZPa1zJQcNXYQFeYzOlZbhwTw_Rx0d0sgRXUy=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "ftCIbYCfXYQ4tEd4ByCkvVuqjlI2"
    },
    "-MY6PW0VnZbhUTXSjzdb" : {
    "message" : "985 casos suman hoy. En pleno Songkran, a los tailandeses les resultará difícil dejar de lado la fiesta.\n \nhttps://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/2098807/thailand-adds-985-covid-cases-monday-new-record\n\n",
    "postId" : "-MXqi6VDUbzRyBhhhfuG",
    "timeStamp" : 1618253320357,
    "userName" : "Pimper Pamper",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMZPa1zJQcNXYQFeYzOlZbhwTw_Rx0d0sgRXUy=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "ftCIbYCfXYQ4tEd4ByCkvVuqjlI2"
    },
    "-MY90R2G3uSPSw8r6TwB" : {
    "message" : "Sigo pensando que el cambio que te hace N26 es mejor. Si teneís las dos, haced una prueba.\n\nEl único motivo por el que me saqué la Revolut, teniendo ya la N26, es porque N26 no deja sacar una segunda tarjeta para el cónyuge. \nRevolout sí lo permite, aunque en las dos figura el nombre del titular.",
    "postId" : "-MY4N5pmKxoaKlmNGgbj",
    "timeStamp" : 1618297078031,
    "userName" : "Antonio Socías Carrillo",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj7AshIUFLsWtMAIt-aukeSREGitv9ky7chZ3g1vfA=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "CTDLa2Yza3Q5F64l7nIdmpGdX5O2"
    },
    "-MY93Ps449myuv31oiMq" : {
    "message" : "A ver si es verdad.\nEn mi corta experiencia con Tailandia he podido comprobar que la mayoría de las medidas anunciadas por el gobierno nunca entran en vigor o lo hacen de una forma mucho más reducida de lo que anunciaron.\n\nVeremos qué pasa este año con la eliminación progresiva de la cuarentena para turistas vacunados, por ejemplo.",
    "postId" : "-MY6Q_luPl61fAvQtOpm",
    "timeStamp" : 1618297859651,
    "userName" : "Antonio Socías Carrillo",
    "userPhoto" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj7AshIUFLsWtMAIt-aukeSREGitv9ky7chZ3g1vfA=s96-c",
    "userUid" : "CTDLa2Yza3Q5F64l7nIdmpGdX5O2"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the last 2 comments from Firebase real-time database aren't being downloaded. It seems a cache problem, because if I wait for a while (a couple of hours), the information is consistent again.

How can I prevent Firebase to return cached results?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Can you edit your question to show the JSON as text, so that I can try reproducing it? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Question edited. The problem is that when someone writes a new comment on the forum, the message doesn't appear until 2 hours later. It's like the listener is reading data from 2 or 3 hours ago. This problem didn't happen in the past, so I don't know why is it happening.

Comment: Hmm.... it seems to work fine here: https://jsbin.com/fadoxem/3/edit?js,console
Can you see if you can reproduce it in a similar environment, with an equally minimal amount of code?

Comment: Frank, thanks for the answer. This is what I mean; if I open your link, I get the following: 

https://ibb.co/PQbZDzc

If you are pushing data every 2 seconds, the listener should print the new object every 2 seconds as well, right?

Comment: Can you try again? There was a missing `toString()` in the write operation that I fixed here: https://jsbin.com/fadoxem/edit?js,console

Comment: Ok, I see, now it's correct. I will try to reproduce my case with the full branch of replies.

Comment: Let me know when you find sometihng, as I'd be curious to know what it was. Note that the JavaScript/Web SDK for Realtime Database doesn't have built-in disk cache support, so that can't be the cause.

Comment: Yeap, I will publish here the answer when I find the solution. After your answer, I can confirm that is not a Firebase cache thing; I've tried your example with the whole branch in JS Bin and it was working fine. Maybe it has something to do with the useEffect() React Hook. I'm doing something wrong for sure. Anyway, it's time to investigate...

Comment: A thing to try: remove the `return () => ref.off('value', listener);` for testing. If that removed the problem it, it may be that this gets called too early (although I hacve no idea why).

Comment: I've tried removing the `return () => ref.off('value', listener);` and still happens. I don't get it, because if it was an early unsubscribe problem, after closing the website and opening it again, I should see the new data (and I see 'cached' data which is not really 'cached'). Another thing that drives me crazy is that I can't reproduce the issue; the component returns updated data sometimes, and after a few random number of comments, it displays a list of outdated comments again.

Comment: Oh right, you said it's not even showing on refresh. Is the updated data showing int he DB console? If not, it might be cached on the writing device. If it's shown on the console, it might be cached on some intermediary cache - but that is extremely uncommon for web sockets. If that is indeed happening, it might be worth checking the debug logging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#setloglevel

Comment: Frank, I did what you suggested; data is updated in the DB console (see key marked in red, after posting a reply https://ibb.co/XD5VPxm). Afterwards, I went to JS Bin to create a test (https://jsbin.com/voyaxadahe/1/edit?html,js,console), and this was the result https://ibb.co/BnfDqdB. As you can see, the reply marked in red from the first pic doesn't appear. The real-time JSON DB in Firebase is > 16 MB.

Comment: Update: I've run the test again, and a few minutes later, the new reply marked in red appears https://ibb.co/yYC7r29. Definitely, there is some delay on the listeners and data isn't updating instantaneously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231136/discussion-between-frank-van-puffelen-and-erik-martin-jordan).